# Error seen while Clean installing using Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

During a mvn clean install, I see this error -

```
[INFO] Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata

only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You problably have a problem in your settings.xml or in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution - delete the maven metadata xml in m2 repo and try again